# streaming audio player for background play

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, media-player, mpmovieplayercontroller

Currently, I am developing an app in which there is need of play an streaming audio.  I am using `mpmovieplayercontroller` to play streaming audio.  It is working fine for me. However, the audio is stopping when the device goes into sleeping mode or enters into background mode.  I want to play audio also in these two mode condition. How can I play streaming audio in these two modes? I am also open to another player.

Comment: This can be done easily in AVFoundation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd check out Matt Gallagher's Audio Streamer.  I use it in an audio streaming application and it works fantastically.  It also supports background streaming, like what you're looking for: https://github.com/mattgallagher/AudioStreamer