# Running a background task for infinite time

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch

I am looking for a way to run a task in background infinitly. I have a streaming player and i try almost everything like background task identifier ,background mode, setKeepMealive, but always it will long lasting to 3 minutes only in background can anybody help me to find out the solution.

Comment: Perhaps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12339930/streaming-audio-player-for-background-play?rq=1

Comment: i tested that but didn't work in background....

Comment: Things have probably changed in the last few years since that code was written. You can't really run servers in the background on iOS. That isn't what these sorts of devices are for.

Comment: i just want to find is there any way to get the task alive more than 3 minutes in ios 7 or above....your help will be appreciated...

Comment: The only background modes that are available are described in the Ios application programming guide on Apple's developer website.  None of them meet your needs.  If you aren't going to publish to the App Store you can use VoIP background mode

Comment: Means if i use the VoIP mode then i will unable to submit my app?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80553/discussion-between-ghanshyam-tomar-and-paulw11).

Comment: If you use VoIP mode but your app isn't a VoIP app then it will be rejected. If you are streaming audio from the device microphone then your app is arguably a VoIP app. If you are streaming from a file then no

Comment: If you are receiving a network stream and playing the audio, like, say Spotify, then you can use audio background mode

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW26

Comment: ok i will watch out that...

Comment: is there apple sample code for background music player or MPMovie player that kind of..?

Comment: Probably. I haven't look. The programming guide is here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/AudioSessionBasics/AudioSessionBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007875-CH3-SW1 - look at AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback

Comment: hey @Paulw11 i need your help can you answer my small question-if i use play sound in device from any method than   "  [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];"
will effect on the sound that i was playing or it will work only if play sound using "AVAudioPlayer"......?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know.  I know a bit about background modes but nothing really about AVAudioPlayer - Why not post another question?

Comment: ok dude...tnx anyway....